# sql count distinct correct

Tags: sql, count

*I HAVE A QUESTION
You manage a pay application where members can transfer money to each other (one-to-one in each transaction). All transactions are recorded in the DB.
Write a SQL program (use the sql_and_logic_pay_app_ds.xlsx file) that shows which member has the most friends. please assist if my syntax is correct.

```
SELECT TO,
(COUNT(DISTINCT To) + COUNT(DISTINCT From)) as TotalFriends
FROM Sql_and_logic_pay_app_ds
GROUP BY TO
ORDER BY TotalFriends DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

THIS IS THE TABLE

```
|      FROM     |     TO   |     DATE     |  TOTAL    |
|        12     |     34   |  13/09/2018  |    155    | 
|        17     |     1    |  13/09/2018  |    334    |
|        12     |     20   |  13/09/2018  |    384    |  
|        12     |     11   |  13/09/2018  |    994    |
|        20     |     8    |  13/09/2018  |    602    |
```

Comment: SQL queries aren't really "programs"...

Comment: is this a trick-question? The first sentence mentions only "members" transferring money between themselves, while the second sentence says "friends" - but there isn't anything in the question that defines what makes someone a "friend" or not.

Comment: i would group by from and count only the TO column as "friends" , but it is laike dai said hard tp guess, as we don't know what friends actually are

Comment: probably the user that appears the most in from and to colums

Comment: please advise correct syntax

Comment: So what do the numbers mean in the `FROM` and `TO` columns?